# DateDiff Or Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My question is that these both live in the same table. How would I be able to get a validated date diff from them? My end goal is to get the average number of days it takes from the top to the bottom. And the percentage rate of the conversion.

```
select *  from contactworkflow where contactworkflow.contactkey = contactworkflow.contactkey
       AND   (    contactworkflow.wfstagekey = 2
                AND contactworkflow.wftaskkey = 74)
```

Both have a different wfdate that i need to get the difference to. I was going to do a datefiff but wasn't sure how to write that.

```
select *  from contactworkflow where contactworkflow.contactkey = contactworkflow.contactkey
   AND   (    contactworkflow.wfstagekey = 4
            AND contactworkflow.wftaskkey = 49)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the results you expect.  The explanation doesn't do the problem justice.

Comment: I'm sorry but your query does not make sense. What would you accomplish by `where contactworkflow.contactkey = contactworkflow.contactkey`?  Also what dates are you talking about?  You may want to post your test data and the expected result.

Comment: Agreed that the question wording is poor, but I think I understand what dates you want to find the difference between. I do not understand what percentage you want computed. Please explain that further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the datediff part:

```
declare @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime

select @date1 = wfdate
from contactworkflow
where contactworkflow.contactkey = contactworkflow.contactkey
AND contactworkflow.wfstagekey = 2
AND contactworkflow.wftaskkey = 74

select @date2 = wfdate
from contactworkflow
where contactworkflow.contactkey = contactworkflow.contactkey
AND contactworkflow.wfstagekey = 4
AND contactworkflow.wftaskkey = 49

-- dd means difference in days
select datediff(dd, @date1, @date2)
```